# Xamarin Microcharts error: The type or namespace name 'Entry' does not exist in the namespace 'Microcharts'

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I try to display a chart from Microcharts, but I receive this error:

```
/Users/pizhev/Documents/WeatherLocationInfo 1.6.8/WeatherLocationInfo/MainPage.xaml.cs(27,27): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Entry' does not exist in the namespace 'Microcharts' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) (WeatherLocationInfo)
```

[image: Xamarin Microcharts error]

I fallow this link: [Tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-microcharts-app/) and before two months this method work perfectly.

So when I try to change:

```
using Entry = Microcharts.Entry;
```

to

```
using Entry = Microcharts.ChartEntry;
```

I receive a many errors like this:

```
/Users/pizhev/Documents/WeatherLocationInfo 1.6.8/WeatherLocationInfo/MainPage.xaml.cs(243,243): Error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Xamarin.Forms.Entry' to 'Microcharts.ChartEntry' (CS1503) (WeatherLocationInfo)
```

and this:

```
/Users/pizhev/Documents/WeatherLocationInfo 1.6.8/WeatherLocationInfo/MainPage.xaml.cs(44,44): Error CS1061: 'ChartEntry' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no accessible extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'ChartEntry' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (WeatherLocationInfo)
```

[image: Microcharts errors]

So what is changed in Microcharts and how can I fix this errors ?

Comment: MicroCharts changed the name of their class from `Entry` to `ChartEntry`

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet-ad/Microcharts/issues/4

Comment: Ok, but how can I fix other errors while I change Entry to ChartEntry ?

Comment: do NOT post code or errors as images.  Get rid of `using Entry = Microcharts.Entry;` this is just making the problem worse